# What's the standard way not to show CGI scripts?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd

I've set up a CGI directory using the `userdir` mod in Apache. I'm using configs as general as possible to have them appliable to other users on my laptop. I got to a point where I can run the script using this URL:

```
http://localhost/~tomas/cgi-bin/hw.cgi
```

But I also put a link to my `public_html` in the server's root directory at `/var/www/html`, so when the `localhost` URL is called, I get the index with a link to my dir at `localhost/tomas`. The link works fine and brings up another index, one of my user. Now, the private cgi-bin is at `/home/*/public_html/cgi-bin`, so I can see the `cgi-bin` when I get the private index. Now, when I enter this directory, I get another index with the CGI's. Which is fine with me, though I'm not sure if this is considered secure. But if I call a CGI from there, it doesn't execute and shows instead. This is the problem.

As far as I know, it's about Apache not viewing

```
http://localhost/tomas/cgi-bin/hw.cgi
```

as

```
http://localhost/~tomas/cgi-bin/hw.cgi
```

I've been looking for a directive that would make it work, but can't find it. I'm not even quite sure what's at my disposal - a directive or what else?

Here's my `usermod.conf`:

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    UserDir public_html
    UserDir disabled root

    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
        AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit Indexes
        Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
        <Limit GET POST OPTIONS>
            Require all granted
        </Limit>
        <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
            Require all denied
        </LimitExcept>
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/*/public_html/cgi-bin>
        Options ExecCGI
        AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: `cgi-bin` is often (e.g. in the RHEL7 httpd package) placed alongside the `html` directory and not under it...

Comment: @thrig I followed the instruction in the official Apache tutorial. See the last point in this subsection: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/cgi.html#configuring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `cgi-bin` directory can be reached through a separate path, one way to do it is to copy the `Directory` section with the alternate path, right below the other one, e.g.:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/*/cgi-bin>
    Options ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
</Directory>
```

This should also disable the directory listings.

If you'd prefer to have indexes enabled, either add `Indexes` to `Options` or make it inherit its parent options by changing `ExecCGI` to `+ExecCGI`, e.g.

```
<Directory /var/www/html/*/cgi-bin>
    Options Indexes ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
</Directory>
```

I'd prefer using `Options Indexes ExecCGI` over `Options +ExecCGI` since this way you won't be inheriting any undesired options.

Comment: Why are indexes disabled now?

Comment: @tomas because `Options` does not include `Indexes` and it overwrites the `Options` set in the parent directory. I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks. I also used a syntax with `SetHandler`, which apparently disables indexes. `AddHandler` works fine.